# My exported dae is corrupted

Tags: modeling, rigging, objects, bones, dae

I'm trying to export a model, but it keeps corrupting.

Here is the original model
[image: original model]

And here is the dae after exporting

[image: poor maki after exporting]

How do i fix this issue? can anyone explain?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share the model https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1j3Av3M2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1j3Av3M2/) here, its pretty messed up when exported